# Overwrite file - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, overwrite

I have the below code which tests if a file exists in a specific location. If file does not exist, save the file. What I want is, in case file exists, to overwrite it. Any help?

```
If Dir(FPath & "\" & FName) <> "" Then
    MsgBox "File " & FPath & "\" & FName & " already exists"
Else
    NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
End If
```

Comment: Use `Kill` to delete it if it exists first.

Comment: Pad `NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName` with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`. If the file exists, it will be overwritten

Comment: @SiddharthRout i use the kill method as  braX suggest & is working perfectly. Which of both method is better?

Comment: @braX post it as an answer to void it!

Comment: I posted that comment because you asked "How to overwrite". There is no hard and fast rule. Different ways to achieve what you want. Just remember to check if the file is readonly before killing it ir using `SaveAs` else you will get error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to delete it first if it exists. That's the easy way. And as  Siddharth Rout suggested, there is no harm in also turning off the ReadOnly attribute just in case it may be set to Read Only.

```
sFullFile = FPath & "\" & FName
If Dir(sFullFile) <> "" Then
  SetAttr sFullFile, vbNormal
  Kill sFullFile
End If
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=sFullFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Use kill to delete the file

```
If Dir(FPath & "\" & FName) <> "" Then Kill (FPath & "\" & FName)
```

I would recommend storing the filepath and name in a single variable to avoid repeating yourself

```
FLocation = (FPath & "\" & FName)
If Dir(FLocation) <> "" Then Kill (FLocation)
```